# Counting loop runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am searching through a few files for certain info and want to count the occurrence.

The first time the loop and the counter working just fine but all other results are "0".

```
for c, info in enumerate(searchKeys): # loop over searchKeys list
    counter = 0 # set counter
    for line in currentFile: # loop over lines in current file
        if info in line: # search for info in line
            counter += 1 # count +1 if info found

    out.write(  "\nInfo: " + str(info) + "\n" +
                "Occurrence: " + str(counter) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need return to the start of the file

```
counter = 0 # set counter
currentFile.seek(0) # add this line
```

more details [file_seek](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/file_seek.htm)

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks for the link